# How to see the hidden html source code in Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am working with the [basic slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/) plugin. My slider works fine but I need to change the format of the navigation buttons named as 1 2 3  in that plugin.

In the  index page html mark up, I can't find the source code html tags related to that navigation elements but when I inspect the element, I can see an ordered list bearing the elements appears.

Please let me know hot to see the  hidden html tags. I need to modify the same

Comment: in the js for the slider, do a search for `showmarkers` and the where that property is checked and true, that's where it will make that slide paginator

Comment: Pete , If i want to rename that navigation bars 1,2,3 as ONE , TWO and THREE  ,I need to modify them in the html tags. I am confused where to make the change since i do not find that related code in the html part of  the plugin that i have downloaded

Comment: read my comment properly it is in the js file

Comment: hi thank for your comment pete, since i am a beginner, your patient help will be a greater help for me. I searched for the show markers in the js but  no where i found the numbers 1 2 or 3 to replace with names of my choice.

Comment: it will be in a loop - most likely it will count the number of slides and do a loop from 0 to slide length and then just output the variable (which will be the number).